# Dynamic sql search in php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to create a dynamic search functionality.

**Goal :** allowing user to search by email (if not empty), if empty (by last name), if both are not empty, than by both, etc.

I know I can write if statement depicting every scenario and than insert SQL command based on that, question is can this be handled in a more simplified manner. Thanks for your help.

Current function set up does OR across all fields, values are coming from $_POST:

```
find_transaction($email,$last_name,$first_name, $transaction_id) 
{
    GLOBAL $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM transactions WHERE ";
    $query .= "email='{$email}' ";
    $query .= "OR last_name='{$last_name}' ";
    $query .= "OR first_name='{$first_name}' ";
    $query .= "OR transaction_id='{$transaction_id}' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY date DESC";
    $email = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    confirm_query($email);
    return $email;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time, it's not too much work. Basically build your WHERE statement dynamically based off your POST variables, using a series of if statements.

For example:

```
$where_statement = "";

// First variable so is simpler check.
if($email != ""){
    $where_statement = "WHERE email = '{$email}'";
}


// Remaining variables also check if '$where_statement' has anything in it yet.
if($last_name != ""){
    if($where_statement == ""){
        $where_statement = "WHERE last_name = '{$last_name}'";
    }else{
        $where_statement .= " OR last_name = '{$last_name}'";
    }
}

// Repeat previous 'last_name' check for each remain variable.
```

SQL statement would change to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions
              $where_statement
              ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Now, the SQL will only contain filters depending on what values are present, so someone puts in just email, it would generate:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions
              WHERE email = 'smith@email.com'
              ORDER BY date DESC";
```

If they put in just last name, it would generate:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions
              WHERE last_name = 'Smith'
              ORDER BY date DESC";
```

If they put both, would generate:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions
              WHERE email = 'email@email.com' OR last_name = 'Smith'
              ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Etc., etc.

You could add as many variables you wish here, and basically if the specific variable is not blank, it will add it to the "$where_statement", and depending on if there is anything in the "$where_statement" yet or not, it will decide to start with = "WHERE ", or append .= " OR" (notice the '.=' and the space before 'OR'.

Comment: Glad it helped. I use this technique often when applying filters to reports.. Ones that mean this should be the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

Better use Data Interactive table : http://datatables.net/

It's useful and no SQL-injection :) Good luck !

Comment: I don't see how this address the question at all? You've just provided a link to a javascript library. Could you at least provide some info on why or how this answers the question! Thanks